# If statements using list comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to build a dataframe containing columns which are conditional. My code:

```
from faker import Faker
import pandas as pd
import random
fake = Faker()
def create_rows_faker(num=1):
    output = [{"name":fake.name(),
                   "address":fake.address(),
                   "name":fake.name(),
                   "email":fake.email()} for x in range(num)]
    return output
```

produces

```
df = pd.DataFrame(create_rows_faker(3))
df
```

[image]

How can I change the definition of `ouput` so that if I had a variable `if name_column == '1'` then include this in output (and don't include otherwise), and similarly with name and email?

Comment: What would be wrong with removing `"name": fake.name(),` from your current code and instead adding `if name_column == '1': for x in range(num): output[x]["name"] = fake.name()`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a standard for loop instead of overcomplicating the comprehension.

```
def create_rows_faker(num=1, name_col = True, address_col = True, email_col = False):
    output = []
    for x in range(num):
        out = {}
        if name_col:
            out["name"] = fake.name()
        if address_col:
            out["address"] = fake.address()
        if email_col:
            out["email"] = fake.email()
        output.append(out)
    return output
```

Comment: I tried this initially but I didn't like the amount of ifs inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using a dictionary of function and a list of the keys:

```
def create_rows_faker(num=1, use=('name', 'address', 'email')):
    options = {"name":fake.name,
               "address":fake.address,
               "email":fake.email}
    use = set(use)
    options = {k:f for k,f in options.items() if k in use}
    output = [{k:f() for k,f in options.items()} for x in range(num)]
    return output

pd.DataFrame(create_rows_faker(3, use=['name']))
```

output:

```
                 name
0  Tracy Alexander MD
1        Mark Winters
2        Lori Edwards
```

Comment: List as a default parameter is a shortcut to serious bugs later on.

Comment: @matszwecja like what? The list is not mutated here

Comment: I made it a tuple, but this doesn't change a thing (I agree this would if I was mutating `use` in the function)

Comment: I just think it's something that should be avoided wherever possible. You never know how the code might change in the future and such things might be a nightmare to debug later on.